# sap.m.DatePicker is not displaying Date

Tags: model, datepicker, odata, sapui5

I am working on SAPUI5 Application using SAPUI5 Lib Version 1.44.19.
I have used `sap.m.DatePicker` for displaying date is bind two way JSON model which is fetching data from oData Service v1.0.

Before binding the oData Date to JSON model, I am doing Date Formatting like :

```
"ProjectFinishDate": Formatter.getDateToServerDate(oData.PlanProjEdate)
```

Respective Formatter Function :

```
getDateToServerDate: function (date) {
        if (date) {
            var d4 = date.getTime();
            var TimezoneOffset = new Date(0).getTimezoneOffset();
            var off = TimezoneOffset * 60 * 1000;
            var sec = d4 + off;
            var date1 = new Date(sec);
            date1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            return date1;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
}
```

Respective XML binding is :

```
<DatePicker id="idInitAppOEInfoFinishDate" dateValue="{ path: 
'oMdlInitApprovalDtlHeader>/ProjectFinishDate' }"                                    
displayFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" class="padLeft0px" visible="  
{oMdlFieldsVisibility>/ProjectFinishDateVisible}"                                    
enabled="{oMdlFieldsVisibility>/ProjectFinishDateEditable}"                                  
change="onChangeFinishDate">
```

console output of the oData Service Date after getting formatted.

```
Thu Oct 18 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

And the output for `DataPicker` is blank.

Comment: OData V1 is pretty old. Are you sure it's not V2? Does reading a collection result in 
 `"d": { "results": [...] }` or just `"d": [...]`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the SAP API, you should not use `dateValue`.

> Although possible to bind it, the recommendation is not to do it. When binding is needed, use value property instead.
>   https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DateTimeField/methods/getDateValue

Since your main problem seems to be timezone related, here is a different approach:

```
<DatePicker 
    value="{ 
        path: 'oMdlInitApprovalDtlHeader>/ProjectFinishDate', 
        type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', 
        formatOptions: { style: 'medium', strictParsing: true , UTC: true }
    }" />
```

That way your dates will be in coordinated universal time (UTC).

https://ui5hub.com/dealing-with-timezones-in-sapui5/